# The request includes at least one invalid\/malformed connection photo id

Tags: google-streetview-publish

I'm using Google StreetView Publish API to connect photos in a virtual tour and to some external photos on Google StreetView such as a road.

This is the API I use:
https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/reference/rest/v1/photo/update

And this is the body of the request:

```json
{
    "pose": {
        "heading": 26,
        "latLngPair": {
            "latitude": 47.707604844777,
            "longitude": -124.41849471719
        }
    },
    "places": [
        {
            "place_id": "ChIJvcvraDvfjVQR45a-VRk0lGs"
        }
    ],
    "connections": [
        {
            "target": {
                "id": "CAoSLEFGMVFpcE5fWGtUZTFWV3dxRm9tOEFlRHVmYVdvTmdDR2NueVZ0dzhid0ZX"
            }
        },
        {
            "target": {
                "id": "rQfq6hLfyFVfC0V43rrWDw"
            }
        }
    ],
    "captureTime": {
        "seconds": "1653027016"
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this error message when I'm trying to add external panorama ID (`{"target":{"id": "rQfq6hLfyFVfC0V43rrWDw"}}` to the `connections` array.

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "The request includes at least one invalid\/malformed connection photo id.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com\/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
                "metadata": {
                    "EXTERNAL_MESSAGE": "The request includes at least one invalid\/malformed connection photo id."
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Does Google let to connect your panoramas to the Google StreetViews panoramas such as street photos, etc? Or what I was doing wrong? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not link your panoramas directly to Google Street View panoramas.

For a while, Google connected the tours automatically, if they were in a certain range. They stopped doing this and undid those connections, so at the moment both exist side by side on the same map.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. How do you know that? Is there an article or documentation on the internet that tells about these changes?

Comment: @RomanGrinev We are working with the API for several years, so this is the experience we gathered during that time. Unfortunately, there is no official documentation for those details, that I am aware of.